# How to insert rows for missing data in R if locations of missing data is unknown?

Tags: r, insert, rows, na, missing-data

I'm trying to correct my dataset for statistical analysis. I have found that there are missing data points and that the timestamps in the dataset are often incorrect which leads to a hard time correcting the dataset. 
My dataset (should) contain 20 data points containing x, y, z values of the same time-stamp (20Hz), however, due to a processing error it is either 24 or 12 (with some exceptions). 
The problem is that it is actually 20Hz, the data display is wrong not the amount of data points, except for where I do miss points. Together this becomes a complicated issue. 
What I have found to be true is that for every six seconds there always needs to be 120 data points and if this is not true, there are data points missing, all other missing points are due to the timestamps being incorrect. 
The issues in short:

```
- Incorrect timestamps with 20Hz (x, y, z) recordings
- Missing data points with unknown location
- Only known factor: ever 6 seconds of data MUST contain 120 data points
```

The following table shows a small part of the dataset (Freq: occurrence of UTC_time)

```
UTC_date    UTC_time       x       y       z    Freq
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -133    918     319     24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -194    1030    203     24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -192    1002    127     24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -154    905     36      24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -71     938     31      24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -206    1071    -43     24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -381    1127    -65     24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -373    927     -25     24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -457    951     -113    24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -436    1023    -189    24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -294    1068    -113    24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -257    943     -92     24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -291    981     -145    24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -46     927     -8      24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -82     932     79      24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -122    812     355     24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -708    806     175     24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -776    800     197     24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -807    748     351     24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -836    790     478     24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -597    502     943     24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -863    852     59      24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -485    732     319     24
11/04/2018  11:02:58    -447    766     117     24
11/04/2018  11:02:59    -497    997     -49     12
11/04/2018  11:02:59    -582    991     -63     12
```

What I've already tried and what I'm currently trying:
I've tried to make another df containing empty cells that could be filled in with the available data, this doesn't work because I do not know which are actually missing.
I have been trying to write some sort of fix with several if (loop) functions. However, because I'm new to R, this is going very slow and giving me many errors.

What I would like to have: a dataset with correct timestamps and include missing points as "NA", so that every second has 20 data points (even if some are "NA").

Comment: Hi, just to confirm I got your question correct: You want to insert NA rows for the seconds where there are not enough datapoints? What do you want to do for the seconds that contain to many datapoints?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! I'm sorry if it wasn't entirely clear. What the data shows as 24 occurrences of one second is an error in the processed data, this should be 20 points only. What makes it complicated is that there are seconds that actually do have data points missing. So, my problem is: I have incorrect timestamps which I cannot correct since I'm missing data points and due to the incorrect timestamps I don't know which ones are missing. The only thing I do know is that every set of 6 seconds must hold 120 points.

Comment: So basically if there are 24 datapoints the last 4 would have to be shifted to the next second?

Comment: Yes, however, I can't simply do that for all because of the points that are actually missing, I think this will create a shift in my dataset

Comment: Yeah. That will be a bit difficult, but probably doable with some looping magic. So If there are less than 120 points in 6 seconds you would probably just fill the seconds which have less then 20 points after this shift with NA rows?

Comment: How many points you need per second? - 20 ?